# сумма элементов массива

Tags: c, массивы

Как найти сумму элементов массива, расположенных между максимальным и минимальным элементами массива, не включая максимальное и минимальное значение в си??

Comment: Находите минимальный элемент, находите максимальный элемент, суммируете элементы, находящиеся между ними. В чем,собственно, проблема?

Comment: Учитесь формулировать свои мысли. Сумму максимального и минимального элементов массива, или сумму элементов между максимальным и минимальным элементами массива (включительно, нет)?

Comment: если бы я знал как просуммировать элементы между ними не задавал бы вопрос (

Comment: @Harry извеняюсь за неточность в вопросе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы найти минимум:

1. Заводите переменную для минимального значения, в неё заносите значение первой ячейки массива - array[0].
2. Заводите переменную для индекса минимального значения, заносите в неё 0.
3. В цикле от второй до последней ячейки выполняете сравнение значения ячейки с переменной минимума. Если значение ячейки (array[i], где i - счётчик цикла) меньше значения переменной минимума, присваиваем значение ячейки минимуму, а переменной индекса присваиваем индекс текущей ячейки i.

Выполняем те же действия для максимума с новыми переменными.

В результате в переменных индекса мы имеем индексы минимального и максимального значения. Осталось завести переменную для суммы, проинициализировать нулём и в цикле от одного индекса до другого посчитать сумму ячеек: sum += array[i], где i - счётчик цикла. Обратите внимание, что индекс максимального элемента может быть меньше индекса минимального.

UPD: если в сумму не нужно включать минимальное и максимальное значение, тогда сумму надо искать так: for (int i = index1 + 1; i < index2; i++).

Answer (score 0):

В цикле перебираем элементы массива и сравниваем между собой, находя минимум и максимум.

Пройдясь по массиву от начала и до конца, на руках имеем индекс минимального элемента и индекс максимального.

Теперь мы можем запустить цикл по новой, что бы просумировать все элементы.

Comment: Сумму элементов массива, находящихся между минимальным и максимальным значением, не включая макс и мин значение